# Problems with 'this' in prototype object

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

So I created a prototype based object like:

```
// constructor
const MyFactory = function () {
    this._myProperty = {
        MyType1: '...',
        MyType2: '...'
    };

    this._converters = [{
        name: 'X'
        outgoingConverter: this._convertToX
    },
    {
        name: 'Y'
        outgoingConverter: this._convertToY
    }];
    // ...
}

MyFactory.prototype._convertToX = function (myObjArray) {
    console.log(this._myProperty); // undefined
    const convertedObjArray = _.map(myObjArray, (obj) => {
        console.log(this._myProperty); // undefined
        const MyObject = this._myProperty[obj.type]; // throws error
        return MyObject ? new MyObject() : undefined;
    });
    //...
};

MyFactory.prototype._dispatch = function (myObjArray) {
    _.forEach(this._converters, (converter) => {
        converter.outgoingConverter(myObjArray);
    });
};

// somewhere in this code I am calling this._dispatch(someObjArray)
```

I am trying to access `this._myProperty` from inside the `.map()` function, but I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'MyType1' of undefined

There is something wrong with the `this context` in my code, I think.
From my understanding [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) preserve the enclosing context of `this`, so I don't understand what's wrong.

**Question**:
Why is `this._myProperty` undefined in my `_convertToX` function?
How can I access `_myProperty` from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `converter.outgoingConverter(myObjArray);` the `outgoingConverter` is a reference to `_convertToX`. However, the `this` is `converter`! In the constructor you might want to use `this._convertToX.bind(this)` to force `this`.

Comment: thanks so much! No idea how I couldn't see that... now I changed right inside my `_converters` array: `outgoingConverter: this._convertToX.bind(this)`

Comment: @lenny You were right, that arrow functions preserve `this`. But that doesn't help when you have the wrong `this` ☺ ;)